# How to turn off auto space before '{' in VS2016 C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, autoformatting

Everytime I write code that is followed by an opening bracket, VS2016 puts a space before the bracket.

```
public void MyFunction() { };
//......................^....
```

I want it to look like

```
public void MyFunction(){ };
```

I disabled every single auto-spacing option in the the c# text-editor options and I can't get this working. Where is this option hiding?

Comment: This is not answer to your question, but. If you want to share your code with others, please, do not doing this specific format. Please, follow to common convention https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: There is no product called VS2015. You mean Visual Studio 2015. Besides, what you ask results unreadable code `public void MyFunction(){`.

Comment: Actually, I would recommend you to follow Microsoft guidelines as it makes code uniform, readable and clear for all developers. Imho, it even does look better with this space, but looks the best with a new line.

Answer (score 2):

Did you disable pretty listing? This should stop your code auto re-formatting.

[image: Screenshot of Options dialogue]

Comment: Love the "Basic" -> "Advanced" hierarchy! You couldn't make it up! Upvote for figuring this out.

Comment: Disabling this option does nothing for me. The auto-format still kicks in whatever I type.

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, you also have per language spacing possibilities that you might review.

Later edit: OP said that "I disabled every single auto-spacing option in the the c# text-editor options". Maybe someone will need this panel too. And it cannot be posted as a comment.

[image: Per language spacing formatting]

Comment: This works for the opening parentheses, but I want to do the same thing but for the code brackets. I edited my question so you can see what I mean.